# Is it possible to make Latex restart the figure counter whenever a section is used?

Tags: floats, sectioning, numbering

I know i can use `\setcounter{figure}{0}` to achieve want i want but this would mean i have to add this command after every section. I was wondering if its possible to write a command such that every time i use `\section{}`, it automatically sets the figure numbering to 0.

Like: If `\section{}` used, then `\setcounter{figure}{0}`

I would like the figures to show up as Figure 1-1 so the chngctr package doesnt work.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please clarify how the figure numbers should be displayed: (a) as 1, 2, 3, etc each time a new section begins, or as n.1, n.2, n.3, etc, where the previx number `n` is the number of the associated section.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LaTeX has the command `\counterwithin` for this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\counterwithin{figure}{section}
\begin{document}
\section{First}
\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\fbox{FIRST}
\caption{First}
\end{figure}
\section{Second}
\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\fbox{SECOND}
\caption{Second}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: is there a way to change the "." to "-" in the counterwithin?

Comment: you can always redefine `\thefigure`, that is quite independant. E.g. `\renewcommand\thefigure{\thesection--\arabic{figure}}`

Answer (score 0):

I save a copy of `\section` and then redefine it so that resets the figure counter immediately prior to calling on the saved copy of `\section`.

To change the style of the typeset figure number, renew the definition of `\thefigure`, done here as `\renewcommand\thefigure{\thesection--\arabic{figure}}`, so that the first figure of each new section will have the number `<section number>--1`.  (also works with appendices).

```
\documentclass{article}
\let\svsection\section
\def\section{\setcounter{figure}{0}\svsection}
\renewcommand\thefigure{\thesection--\arabic{figure}}
\begin{document}
\section{First}
\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\fbox{FIRST}
\caption{First}
\end{figure}
\section{Second}
\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\fbox{SECOND}
\caption{Second}
\end{figure}

\begin{appendix}
\section{Appendix}
\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\fbox{APPENDIX}
\caption{Appendix}
\end{figure}
\end{appendix}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! THis is almost perfect but it doesnt work with Appendices where the Section is not a number but a letter

Comment: @AustinBenny Without a sample code from you, it may depend.  Perhaps this as an alternative may work: `\renewcommand\thefigure{\thesection--\arabic{figure}}`.  If not, let me know.

Comment: that works! thanks

Comment: @AustinBenny Please see my edit.

Comment: latex counters have a built in mechanism to reset all subordinate counters

Comment: well LaTeX can reset counters, you know that from sections in chapter or subsections in sections. So patching is really not needed.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I think I am missing your point.

Comment: you should not redefine `\section`, just specify that whenever `section` counter is incremented that `figure` resets just the same way that `subsection` resets.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Well, since I "redefine" it without the use of arguments, I sort of don't consider it as redefining it.  But more to your point, I'm not sure I know how to automatically reset `figure` by way of `\stepcounter{section}`.  Though perhaps you refer to Mico's answer.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I acknowledge the correctness of your answer, in preference to this one...but that's not how I did it.

Comment: Yes I meant Mico's answer for old timers (like me:-) or Ulrike's answer for the youngsters (like Ulrike...)